# How to related a field to another from other model?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I would like to bring the field `client_order_ref`from `sale.order` model to `mrp.workorder` . I did it like this but when I run, It does not show any value. What could be wrong?

```py
class MRPWorkOrder(models.Model): 
    _inherit = 'mrp.workorder'

    nro_viaje_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order', string="Nro de Viaje")
    nro_viaje = fields.Char(related='nro_viaje_id.client_order_ref', store=True)
```

The view extension:

```xml
<record id="view_workorder_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.workorder.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">mrp.workorder</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_production_workorder_tree_editable_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="html">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='workcenter_id']" position="after">
              <field name="nro_viaje" string="Viaje" optional="show" readonly="True">
              </field>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: The field declaration is ok. Can you share the XML view that includes the field?

Comment: yes, here it is
  <record id="view_workorder_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">  
       <field name="name">view.workorder.form.inherit</field>  
          <field name="model">mrp.workorder</field>  
          <field name="inherit_id"  
 ref="mrp.mrp_production_workorder_tree_editable_view"/>  
       <field name="arch" type="html">  
           <xpath expr="//field[@name='workcenter_id']" position="after">  
                 <field name="nro_viaje" string="Viaje" optional="show" readonly="True">  
                 </field>  
           </xpath>  
       </field>  
    </record>

Comment: I still have not solved it. I do not know why it does not show me any value and nither error

Comment: Did you include your `xml` file in `manifest` file?

Comment: yes, I did it but it still nothing

Answer (score 0):

This is the error it shows me when I run it @Tiki

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /opt/odoo/odoo/custom_addons/mrp_custom/views/views.xml:37, near
<record id="view_workorder_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">view.workorder.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">mrp.workorder</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_production_workcenter_tree_view_inherit"/>
            <field name="arch" type="html">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='workcenter_id']" position="after">
                    <field name="nro_viaje" string="Viaje" optional="show" readonly="True"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: What version of odoo do you have? Are you sure it is version 10 as the label indicates? Because the view that you inherit in the body of the question (`mrp_production_workorder_tree_editable_view`) does not exist in odoo-10 but does in odoo-14.

Comment: I am sorry Tiki, I forgot tell you I am using odoo 14

Comment: Is there another way to related the field?

Comment: I tested and it works fine. The only reason that `client_order_ref` may be empty is because `nro_viaje_id` is null or because the order does not have that field filled.

Comment: Tiki, and would you tell me how to test if client_order_ref is empy?